# aws lambda loop timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a function in aws lambda, execute a ffmpeg command, and upload the finished video to S3, I set the lambda timeout of 5 minutes, test in the console is normal, but I used in the django PYTHON SDK boto3.invoke calls  timeout, and I saw each execution function S3 which will produce 3 record, it shows that lambda has been running successfully and uploaded to S3, but why would it have been repeatedly run non-stop until 5 minutes? Is there anyone who can help me? Thank you very much.

```html
client_lambda = boto3.client('lambda')

def all_compose_vedio(var):
    response = client_lambda.invoke(
        FunctionName='second_vedio',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(var))
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the timeout of the boto config like this:

```
config = botocore.config.Config(connect_timeout=300, read_timeout=300)
client = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-east-1', config=config)
```

with the correct region, and the timeouts you need
remember that you will be billed twice this way...

I think the reason is that your second lambda is timing out and retrying